# how to check which object was clicked?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recyclerview.I need to excute code just when ImageView is clicked, the layout have a TextBox and a ImageView, now the code is excuted when TextView or ImageView was clicked indifferently.

```
public WordViewHolder(View itemView) {

    super(itemView);

    bicchiereBevuto = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bicchierebevuto);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //cancella il database
    // aggiungere controllo sull oggetto che è stato cliccato,
    // solo se è stata cliccata l'immagine X si deve eseguire il codice

    Integer pos = getLayoutPosition();
    String text = this.bicchiereBevuto.getText().toString();
    text = text.substring(text.length() - 5);

    mDB.deleteBicchiere(text);

    if (mContext instanceof ActivityMain)
        ((ActivityMain) mContext).upDate();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

NOT  itemView.setOnClickListener(this);